# Crawl through all golf course pages with Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to scrape golf course details of all golf courses in the world using this directory:
https://www.golfadvisor.com/course-directory

While I wrote the parse function to scrape the actual courses:

```
def parse_filter_course(self, response):
        
        # checking if it is an actual course page. excluded it for final ran, didnt fully
        # exists = response.css('.CoursePageSidebar-map').get()
        # if exists:

        # the page is split in multiple sections with different amount of details specified on each.
        # I decided to use nested for loop (for section in sections, for detail in section) to retrieve data.
        about_section = response.css('.CourseAbout-information-item')
        details_section = response.css('.CourseAbout-details-item')
        rental_section = response.css('.CourseAbout-rentalsServices-item')
        practice_section = response.css('.CourseAbout-practiceInstruction-item')
        policies_section = response.css('.CourseAbout-policies-item')

        sections = [
            about_section,
            details_section,
            rental_section,
            practice_section,
            policies_section
        ]
        # created a default list dict to add new details from for loops
        dict = defaultdict(list)
        # also have details added NOT from for loop sections, but hard coded using css and xpath selectors.
        dict = {
            'link': response.url,
            'Name': response.css('.CoursePage-pageLeadHeading::text').get().strip(),
            'Review Rating': response.css('.CoursePage-stars .RatingStarItem-stars-value::text').get('').strip(),
            'Number of Reviews': response.css('.CoursePage-stars .desktop::text').get('').strip().replace(' Reviews',''),
            '% Recommend this course': response.css('.RatingRecommendation-percentValue::text').get('').strip().replace('%',''),
            'Address': response.css('.CoursePageSidebar-addressFirst::text').get('').strip(),
            'Phone Number': response.css('.CoursePageSidebar-phoneNumber::text').get('').strip(),
            # website has a redirecting link, did not figure out how to get the main during scraping process
            'Website': urljoin('https://www.golfadvisor.com/', response.css('.CoursePageSidebar-courseWebsite .Link::attr(href)').get()),
            'Latitude': response.css('.CoursePageSidebar-map::attr(data-latitude)').get('').strip(),
            'Longitude': response.css('.CoursePageSidebar-map::attr(data-longitude)').get('').strip(),
            'Description': response.css('.CourseAbout-description p::text').get('').strip(),
            # here, I was suggested to use xpath to retrieve text. should it be used for the fields above and why?
            'Food & Beverage': response.xpath('//h3[.="Available Facilities"]/following-sibling::text()[1]').get('').strip(),
            'Available Facilities': response.xpath('//h3[.="Food & Beverage"]/following-sibling::text()[1]').get('').strip(),
            # another example of using xpath for microdata
            'Country': response.xpath("(//meta[@itemprop='addressCountry'])/@content").get('')
        }
        # nested for loop I mentioned above
        for section in sections:
            for item in section:
                dict[item.css('.CourseValue-label::text').get().strip()] = item.css('.CourseValue-value::text').get('').strip()
        
    yield dict
```

I am struggling with crawling through all golf courses in the directory.

I had few approaches:

1. From previous scraping experience, I used scrapy.spider crawler and multiple parse functions for each step to first: scrape all country links from world directory, second: scrape all states/region links from the country directory, third: scrape courses in the region directory.

But I faced the difficulty right away, since some countries don't have regions/states directory, but rather course directory. And I didn't know how to skip one parse function and instead of scraping state/region links start scraping course details.

2. So I came across crawlspider, and wrote a rule with link extractor to visit only pages with 'courses/' in the path and ignore pages with 'page=', ' in the path, since those were duplicate course links that lead to the same golf course that was scraped multiple times.

```
    class GolfCourseSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = 'golfadvisor'
        allowed_domains = ['golfadvisor.com']
        start_urls = ['https://www.golfadvisor.com/course-directory']
        # use rules to visit only pages with 'courses/' in the path and exclude pages with 'page=1, page=2, etc'
        # since those are duplicate links to the same course
        rules = [
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('courses/'), deny=('page=')), callback='parse_filter_course', follow=True),
        ]
```

With this method I was able to scrape ~20k courses out of 36k.

3. Instead of one start url I extracted country urls and used those as a start urls.
   That gave me 26k courses out of 36k.

Can you suggest a better way of crawling through all course pages?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend usage of [SitemapSpider](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.4/topics/spiders.html) for this case 
as according website's robots.txt - it has sitemaps that contain all 36K course links

```py
import scrapy

class GolfAdvisorComSpider(scrapy.spiders.SitemapSpider):
    name = "golfadvisorcom"
    custom_settings = {"DOWNLOAD_DELAY":1,

                       }
    sitemap_urls = [
        'https://www.golfadvisor.com/sitemap1.xml',
        'https://www.golfadvisor.com/sitemap2.xml'
    ]

    def sitemap_filter(self, entries):
        for entry in entries:
            if "/courses/" in entry.get("loc"):
                yield entry

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
        #parse course data
```

Comment: Thank you! Why would you use sitemap_filter instead of sitemap_rules? i.e. can we rewrite your sitemap_filter with sitemap_rules = [('/courses/bvr/', None), (' /courses/badges/', None),('/courses/feed/', None),('/courses/', 'parse'), ] since I want to exclude links with paths that contain courses with "feed, bvr, badges" in them.