# Scrapy SitemapSpider - How to yield entry from sitemap_filter to parse

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, sitemap

I'm building a SitemapSpider.
I'm trying to filter sitemap entries to exclude entries that contain this substring '/p/' in the link:

```
<url>
       <loc>https://example.co.za/product-name/p/product-id</loc>
       <lastmod>2019-08-27</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
```

According to the [Scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html) , we can define a `sitemap_filter` function:

```
        for entry in entries:
            date_time = datetime.strptime(entry['lastmod'], '%Y-%m-%d')
            if date_time.year >= 2005:
                yield entry
```

In my case I'm filtering on `entry['loc']` instead of `entry['lastmod']`.

Unfortunately I haven't found an example that uses `sitemap_filter` besides the above.

```
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider

class mySpider(SitemapSpider)
    name = 'spiderName'
    sitemap_urls = ['https://example.co.za/medias/sitemap']
    # sitemap_rules = [ ('donut/c', 'parse')]
    
    def sitemap_filter(self, entries):
        for entry in entries:
            if '/p/' not in entry['loc']
                print(entry)
                yield entry
    def parse(self, response):
        ...
```

The code runs fine without the `sitemap_filter` function, but it's not feasible to define all the `sitemap_rules`.

When I run the code above it prints the correct sitemap entries, but it seemingly doesn't proceed to the parse function. The log file shows no errors:

```
2022-05-10 17:02:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-05-10 17:02:00 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-05-10 17:02:00 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-05-10 17:02:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.co.za/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2022-05-10 17:02:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.co.za/medias/sitemap.xml> (referer: None)
2022-05-10 17:02:05 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Received SIGINT, shutting down gracefully. Send again to force 
2022-05-10 17:02:06 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Received SIGINT twice, forcing unclean shutdown
2022-05-10 17:02:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (shutdown)
2022-05-10 17:02:09 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

I'm looking for a way to send the entries yielded by `sitemap_filter` to the `parse` function, or alternatively, a way to filter sitemap entries before scrapy opens the links.

Comment: maybe it should `yield Request(entry)` - and this should get HTML from this URL and send to `parse()`

Comment: your code gives some error messages because you forgot `:` in some places. And I can't connect to `https://example.co.za`. Put code which we could copy and run.

Comment: From my understanding Your code looks like valid. It looks nearly the same as code from [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65129740/10884791).

Comment: According to log output You stopped scraping process in 5 seconds after receiving response with sitemap. From my experience - processing sitemaps with thousands entries can easily exceed 5 seconds.

Comment: code works correctly with my small `sitemap.xml`. But you have `Received SIGINT` so it looks like you stoped code manually and maybe it couldn't  start prarsing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions everyone. Based on @Georgiy's comments and [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65129740/10884791), replacing `entry['loc']` with `entry.get('loc')` is what worked.

```
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider

class mySpider(SitemapSpider)
    name = 'spiderName'
    sitemap_urls = ['https://example.co.za/medias/sitemap']
    # sitemap_rules = [ ('donut/c', 'parse')]
    
    def sitemap_filter(self, entries):
        for entry in entries:
            if '/p/' not in entry.get('loc')
                #print(entry)
                yield entry
    def parse(self, response):
        ...
```